# Using python to match wildcard-expanded string if not proceeded by substring

Tags: python, regex

I have strings full of numbers letters A, C, G, or T and ^ characters such as:

43CGT^TGC35TG^G45C

^ will always precede a sequence of one or more letters.

I want to get all sequences of sequential letters that are not preceded by a ^. So for the example above, I would like to return:

['CGT', 'TG', 'C']

With re, I have tried:

```
re.findall("(?<!\^)[ACGT]+", "43CGT^TGC35TG^G45C")
```

which returns:

```
['CGT', 'GC', 'TG', 'C']
```

But this is incorrect because it is also returning 'GC'. I would like it to group together the "^TGC" substring but instead it is just tossing the T and keeping the GC.

Any idea how to do this correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: And what will be the expected output for "ABC43CGT^TGC35TG^G45C"?

Comment: `re.findall(r"(?<![\^ACGT])[ACGT]+", "43CGT^TGC35TG^G45C")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("(?<![\^ACGT])[ACGT]+", "43CGT^TGC35TG^G45C")
['CGT', 'TG', 'C']
```

I just modified the negative look-behind to also exclude matches that are preceded by characters A,C,G,T.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
re.findall("(?<=\d)[ATGC]+", "43CGT^TGC35TG^G45C")
```

result

```
['CGT', 'TG', 'C']
```